# How can make video with good quality and size in android

Tags: android, video

Want to make a video with good quality and size in Android but seems it not possible! look at Spotify app when run this app one video playing with good size and quality, I decompile Spotify and take video, made my video exact like that width and height and frame rate and fps,... but not work. even made my video exact like the recommendation of Android Developer site but not work... so my question is how can make a video with good quality and size like Spotify video?

Comment: maybe if you show your code we can help you...

Comment: is your question about making a video or about viewing the video in an android app? if the 1st, than it is not related to android and also no programming question. if its the 2nd case show us the code what you have tried so far. Or do you mean recording a video with your app?

Comment: @Fusselchen want viewing video in android app but i try so many ways and so many convertors but always when video playing . its bad quality or bad size ...

Comment: @Ivan its not about programming! my codes is simple , just show video in videoView

Comment: If its not about programming, then you are at the wrong place to ask ;) May be https://video.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this.